# Unable to change font of TextButton using Skin

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx

I'm using uiskin.png, uiskin.atlas, uiskin.json, and default.fnt as ressources for my upcomming code provided by this link.https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data

Firstly I create a `BitmapFont` out of a `ttf` file since it supports any size without getting pixelated.
Then I load `uiskin.json` to my `skin`.After that I remove the default-font and add my generated tff font to the `skin` as `default-font`.

Though I changed the `default-font`, the font has not been changed.
Where lies the problem? How can I change a font of a skin?

Note: I've already tested to display `mainMenuFont50`. The font seems to work fine.

```
public class Screen{
    private BitmapFont mainMenuFont50;
    private Stage stage;
    private Skin skin;
    private TextButton buttons;

    public Screen(GdxGame game){
        //creating BitmapFont from ttf
        generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font/Capture_it.ttf"));
        parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
        parameter.size = 50;
        mainMenuFont50 = generator.generateFont(parameter);
        generator.dispose();

        this.skin = new Skin();
        this.skin.load(Gdx.files.internal("ui/uiskin.json"));
        this.skin.remove("default-font", BitmapFont.class);
        this.skin.add("default-font", mainMenuFont50);

        buttons = new TextButton("Hello World", skin);
        stage.addActor(buttons);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change font of a skin. Construct a skin and add your custom font.

Follow below steps :

- Create a blank skin using default constructor.

  ```
  Skin skin = new Skin();
  ```
- Add required font to the generated skin

  ```
  skin.add("font", mainMenuFont50);
  ```
- Add your atlas file to your skin.

  ```
  skin.addRegion(new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.atlas")));
  ```
- Edit and Load your json file to your skin.

  ```
  skin.load(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
  ```
- your JSON file have reference of “font”

  ```
  {
     font: font
  }
  ```